# Dynamically Populate ACF Select field with Taxonomy Grouped by Parent Category using <optGroup>

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

not sure if possible, but I would love to organize my dynamically populated select group using the outgroup element by group Parent/Child terms. -- I.E

Taxonomy Parent Category 1

- Category 1
- Category 2

Taxonomy Parent Category 2

- Category 1
- Category 2

Currently, I have the code below, how can I modify it to add group heading as parent category? TIA

```
add_filter( 'acf/load_field/name=vendor_category', function( $field ) {
  
  // Get all taxonomy terms
  $article_types = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'lists_plus_category',
    'post_type' => 'lists_plus',  
    'hide_empty' => false
  ) );
  
  // Add each term to the choices array.
  // Example: $field['choices']['review'] = Review
  foreach ( $article_types as $type ) {
    $field['choices'][$type->name] = $type->name;
  }

  return $field;
} );
```

Comment: I don't think ACF supports optgroups for the select type to begin with.